# Aligning HTML special charaters bottom relative to parent

Tags: html, css, special-characters, vertical-alignment, symbols

So I'm building a website for a client in WordPress and the design has **square** full stops on a few headings but the font they have used has **round** full stops.

I have solved this issue with a shortcode '[stop]' and this will return the following code:

```
<span class="square-stop">&#9632;</span>
```

This is a HTML square symbol ■ wrapped in a span for styling.

But I can seem to get it to align bottom with the text. See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9a8x844n/

```
<h1>This is a heading of some kind<span class="square-stop">&#9632;</span></h1>
```

Comment: Looks okay to me in Chrome. What browser are you having this problem on?

Comment: Chrome - http://prntscr.com/4ura7b

Comment: These are both in chrome on mac
JSFiddle http://prntscr.com/4urck3
Devsite http://prntscr.com/4urcqw

Comment: Show the relevant CSS code too and specify where the character should appear. Unless you are doing something special, its glyph sits on the text baseline, but different fonts have different glyphs for the character, possibly with empty space below the visible glyph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the font **Myriad Pro** which was causing this problem in Chrome, I fixed this but setting the .square-stop font as **Arial**.

You can view my fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/9a8x844n/3/

```
.square-stop {font-size: 0.7em; font-family: Arial;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following css to align **square**:

```
h1{
     position:relative;   
}
.square-stop {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical-align: bottom;

http://jsfiddle.net/9a8x844n/2/

```
.square-stop {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```